# Rewarded video ad resume method

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, resume, rewardedvideoad

I'm implementing rewarded video on an application in c++ on ios and android, but the crash happened only on android. It happens only sometimes, when it comes from background to foreground.

I got the message **Abort message: 'rewarded_video::Initialize() must be called before this method.'** on crash report, and I think it`s when the resume method from the rewarded video is called.

Does anybody knows if I have someway of knowing if resume is supposed to be called? Or should it be called whenever the app enters foreground?

Thanks in advance,

Felipe.

Comment: Provide the code that you are using

Comment: Thanks for the attention, I found what caused the error.

Answer (score 4):

I found out what the problem was. My app on android was creating another instance when opened from another source, and that was causing the error message on the rewarded video.

I added **android:launchMode="singleTask"** on the manifest and it worked.